# Disable memcached TCP and UDP?

Tags: memcached

In `memcached.conf` I have:

```
# -l 127.0.0.1
# -p 11211
```

My intent is disabling any TCP or UDP binding, as I don't use the service through anything other than unix sockets.

Is this configuration achieving my desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the version of memcached; with `-l 127.0.0.1 -p 12111` as the only options, memcached will listen on both TCP and UDP port 11211 albeit only on 127.0.0.1.

This is the most typical way of disabling any TCP or UDP binding and setting the permissions to usable for any user on the system.  If you only want specific users to access the socket then the latter could be fine tuned in other ways.

```
   -s /tmp/memcached.sock
   -a 666
```

Per man memcached(1) ...

```
   -a <perms>
          Permissions (in octal format) for Unix socket created with -s option.

   -s <file>
          Unix socket path to listen on (disables network support).
```

... note that regardless of all other options, if `-s` is specified then it will disable all networking support (TCP & UDP) and it will not bind to any interfaces.  It is somewhat misleading to specify `-l 127.0.0.1 ... -s /tmp/memcached.sock`, even though it would accept those options.

Another way to disable memcached networking support is to tell it to listen on port 0.

```
   -p <num>
          Listen on TCP port <num>, the default is port 11211.

   -U <num>
          Listen on UDP port <num>, the default is port 11211, 0 is off.
```

*In the latest versions, the default for -U is 0 (off).*

Aside; While the man page doesn't explicitly say it, `-p 0` will disable TCP too, e.g. `-l 127.0.0.1 -p 0 -U 0` would work, though it's pointless because it would be effectively unusable unless a socket path is specified.